# Multiple touch event in single image view

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiimageview

I would like to implement multiple touch event for single image view. For example, I have an image of India map, where I should be able to capture the touch event of different states. Can someone provide me some idea to implement this in objective c?

Comment: Sorry but I haven't understand. Do you want to intercept a multitouch on the image or you want to intercept the touch on a single state of India?

Comment: You can create hot spot on the image for all the states, and register tap gesture for all the hot spot.

Comment: @vivekDas can you explain some more?

Comment: Hot spot means a circular region, may be a circular semi transparent Views on the image. Then register a tap gesture with the circular View.

Comment: you can also use a SVG of India map which will give states as CALayers and you can detect touch easily on individual states. there are many libraries that help parse SVG like https://github.com/SVGKit/SVGKit, etc.

Comment: @JenJose : Thank you. I will try that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, quite an interesting question. The solution can be achieved in many ways.

Solution 1 :

Get an image with the states in different distinct colors. Then you can get the color at the point of touch and compare it with the color of the state.[image]

So if the color at a point is RGB base 256 is ( 240, 125, 131 ) then the state is Maharashtra.

Note in this picture above some states have the same color so this exact image would not work.

To get the color at a pixel you can refer to [this link](http://www.markj.net/blog/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color).

Solution 2: (Coded in Swift but would work perfectly with Objective C tested with Obj-C link to it)

1. Get all the images of individual states.
2. Make a view a subclass of StateView in IB
3. Set the image and name of State in IB
4. If the touch is within the state it prints the state name as far as now for demo purposes.

Link to the [project](https://github.com/Ibrahimhass/SOAnswerIndiaStates).

References :

[Mark Moeykens Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfrrZfbxFb0&vl=en)

Hope this helps.

Result :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes i did it in one of my application. You need to keep tract of paths for states, then on tap, find the path in which the point lies. 
In my case i had to devide the image with set of rectangles then i just noted down the first & list point (CGPoint) and save the height width of rectangle. Then based on this data i compared whether the point lies in which region.

How to fine the state area ?

You need to manually tap on boundary of area & get the CGPoint from touch default methods as:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let point = touches.first?.location(in: self)
}

override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

    let point = touches.first?.location(in: self)
    touches.forEach { (touch) in
        print(touch.location(in: self))
    }        
}
```